# Is there a way to add multiple columns to a dataframe calculated from moving averages from different columns and/or over different duration

Tags: apache-spark, time-series

I have a dataframe with time-series data and I am trying to add a lot of moving average columns to it with different windows of various ranges. When I do this column by column, results are pretty slow.

I have tried to just pile the `withColumn` calls until I have all of them.

Pseudo code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as pysparkSqlFunctions

## working from a data frame with 12 colums:
## - key as a String
## - time as a DateTime
## - col_{1:10} as numeric values

window_1h =  Window.partitionBy("key")                \
                   .orderBy(col("time").cast("long")) \
                   .rangeBetween(-3600, 0)
window_2h =  Window.partitionBy("key")                \
                   .orderBy(col("time").cast("long")) \
                   .rangeBetween(-7200, 0)
df = df.withColumn("col1_1h", pysparkSqlFunctions.avg("col_1").over(window_1h))
df = df.withColumn("col1_2h", pysparkSqlFunctions.avg("col_1").over(window_2h))
df = df.withColumn("col2_1h", pysparkSqlFunctions.avg("col_2").over(window_1h))
df = df.withColumn("col2_2h", pysparkSqlFunctions.avg("col_2").over(window_2h))
```

What I would like is the ability to add all 4 columns (or many more) in one call, hopefully traversing the data only once for better performance.

Comment: You could write your own UDAF function that does that. It would be a single function on the longest window you have, and internally it would collect averages for all shorter windows in one passage.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to import the functions library as `F` as it looks neater and it is the standard alias used in the official Spark documentation.

The star string, `'*'`, should capture all the current columns within the dataframe. Alternatively, you could replace the star string with `*df.columns`. Here the star explodes the list into separate parameters for the select method.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select(
    "*",
    F.avg("col_1").over(window_1h).alias("col1_1h"),
    F.avg("col_1").over(window_2h).alias("col1_2h"),
    F.avg("col_2").over(window_1h).alias("col2_1h"),
    F.avg("col_2").over(window_1h).alias("col2_1h"),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is significantly faster and cleaner

Comment: Sorry I am removing the accepted answer tag, when I check the debug string of the rdd after this, I still see as many mapPartition operations as there are of added columns so I am suspecting that we can do better? Does this make sense? (I am not the one who down-voted though ;) )

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are looking for. Let me know if you find a solution. I would be interested in seeing it